# C++: copying a struct containing a std::vector efficiently

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, stdvector

```
struct MZEntry
{
    uint32_t machineID;
    bool mode;
    uint32_t area;
    uint32_t occupancy;

    
    using ZList = std::vector<uint32_t>;
    
    ZList authorisationZ;
    ZList blockExceptionZ;
    
    void clear()
    {
        machineID = 0;
        mode = false;
        area = 0;
        occupancy = 0;
        authorisationZ.clear();
        blockExceptionZ.clear();
    }

    MZEntry(){
        clear();
    }

    MZEntry(const MZEntry& mzEntry)
    {
        machineID = mzEntry.machineID;
        mode = mzEntry.mode;
        area = mzEntry.area;
        occupancy = mzEntry.occupancy;
        authorisationZ = mzEntry.authorisationZ;
        blockExceptionZ = mzEntry.blockExceptionZ;
    }
};
```

I have the above structure in my code. Is there any benefit in me explictly declaring the copy-constructor?

Let's say I have two variables

```
MZEntry entry_1;
MZEntry entry_2;
```

if I do `entry_1 = entry_2`, will all the fields in the `entry_2` get copied over to `entry_1` including the vectors in it?

Or is an explict copy-constructor required. Also is the above explict copy-constructor more efficient?

Comment: That's the point and one of the major benefits of using stl; to have automatic copying and moving. You don't need a copy constructor. In your class you don't even need a constructor at all, you can just init the integers to 0 and the vectors are automatically initialized.

Comment: *will all the fields in the entry_2 get copied over to entry_1 including the vectors in it?* - Yes. *Also is the above explict copy-constructor more efficient?* - No, it's worse than what compiler produces, because you don't use member initializer list, so you default initialize each member and then reassign them. Compiler generated copy constructor would copy-initialize all members directly.

Comment: I agree with the points above. However if the vectors contain a lot of data and copying them cost too much time/memory you can consider having  shared_ptrs to your vector. (And that's a tradeoff since then you will have an indirection to access the vectors data).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring a copy constructor is a bad idea. Follow the rule-of-zero whenever you can and don't declare any copy/move constructor or assignment operator or destructor if you don't need custom destructor behavior because the class must manage some resource (and if it has to, always encapsulate that in a class specifically limited to that purpose, following the rule-of-five (or rule-of-three)). See also the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-zero).

If you declare the copy constructor manually you inhibit the implicit definition of the move operations which would be used instead of a copy operations whenever possible to perform a move efficient move (rather than copy) of the members.

For example

```
MZEntry entry_1;
MZEntry entry_2;
/*...*/
entry_1 = std::move(entry_2);
```

With the (implicit) move assignment operator, this allows `entry_1` to just take over the memory which the vector members of `entry_2` allocated. `entry_2` will afterwards be in an unspecified state, but that is often fine. With the manual declaration of your copy constructor there won't be an implicit move assignment operator and the above would perform a full copy of all vector elements, the same as `entry_1 = entry_2` would (with or without your manually defined copy constructor).

Also, as mentioned in the question comments, your implementation of the copy constructor is actually worse performance-wise than the compiler-generated one, although it produces exactly the same behavior in the end.

---

Similarly manual definition of the default constructor can be avoided by using in-class default member initializers instead and letting the compiler generate the default constructor from that.

Calling `.clear()` on the vector members is redundant, since their default constructor will put them into an empty state anyway.

Following the core guidelines you would have:

```
struct MZEntry
{
    uint32_t machineID = 0;
    bool mode = false;
    uint32_t area = 0;
    uint32_t occupancy = 0;

    using ZList = std::vector<uint32_t>;
    
    ZList authorisationZ;
    ZList blockExceptionZ;
};
```

or alternatively (same result, matter of style):

```
struct MZEntry
{
    uint32_t machineID{};
    bool mode{};
    uint32_t area{};
    uint32_t occupancy{};

    using ZList = std::vector<uint32_t>;
    
    ZList authorisationZ{};
    ZList blockExceptionZ{};
};
```

which lets the compiler generate all of the special member functions optimally. And if you need the `clear` method for some other purpose, it can then be implemented simply as

```
void clear() {
    *this = MZEntry();
}
```

or (again matter of style, same result):

```
void clear() {
    *this = {};
}
```

(Although your more explicit implementation of the `clear` member function as such might be more performant overall, since it won't cause memory of the vectors to be released, so that they may then reuse it later without new allocations.)

Comment: Thanks :). Is there a benefit in declaring the constructor as above? or even that is redundant?

Comment: @liv2hak Declaring the copy constructor if you can follow the rule-of-zero has no benefit at all.

Comment: I was asking about the constructor (the normal constructor, or the object constructor) where I am just calling clear() in the above example

Comment: @liv2hak That one is called a _default constructor_. It is required if you want to make sure that the class always has all members properly initialized to zero. However calling `clear` on the `vector` members is pointless. They are empty by default. As you can see in the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-in-class-initializer) it is however preferred to not declare a default constructor manually but instead to use default member initializers in-class, e.g. just write `uint32_t machineID = 0;`, etc. and the constructor can be dropped.

Comment: Doing the inline member initialization instead of a constructor with member initialization list (which your original code didn't do, that was a bad way to initialize) has no immediate benefit other than being shorter. But you can combine that with constructors, e.g. `MZEntry(ZLIst &&blocks) : blockExceptionZ(std::move(blocks)) { }` would still initialize all the skipped members to the right values. Only those, you don't initialize anything twice. So if you have multiple constructors you don't have to repeat the default initialization values over and over and only have to write what's special.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It has the benefit of automatically and correctly propagating `constexpr` (not relevant with `std::vector` members before C++20) and `noexcept` (relevant with `std::vector` members since C++17 and potentially before dependent on the implementation). And assuming C++14 or later (although the question is tagged C++11; OP you should try to upgrade to a newer standard revision) it would also make the class aggregate, allowing for aggregate initialization.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah, that's c++14/17/20. Should have mentioned it has benefits in later standards.